# User-defined deduction guides vs factory functions

Tags: c++, c++17

When writing generic wrapper class templates like the `FooWrapper<WrappeeT>` below, it's convenient to deduce `WrappeeT` when creating the instance of the wrapper class.  For example,  just type `wrap(foo)` instead of typing `wrap<Foo>(foo)`.

Is it better to achieve this:

- with a user-defined deduction guide? Then types `FooWrapper{foo}` to construct the object.
- with an perfect-forwarding factory function? One types `make_wrapper(foo)` or just `wrap(foo)`

By "better" I mean:

- are the two approaches functionally equivalent in terms of type safety (and efficiency)?
- is one more idiomatic than the other since C++17?

I tend to think the deduction guide is better in all aspects, but I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Here's my code (also [live here](https://godbolt.org/z/GrKohe1G9))

```
#include<utility>
#include<cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
struct FooWrapper {
  auto foo() {return wrapped_.special_foo();}
  template <typename V>
  explicit FooWrapper(V&& u) : wrapped_(std::forward<V>(u)) {}
private:
  U wrapped_;
};

// option 1: Additional deduction guide
template<class V> FooWrapper(V) -> FooWrapper<V>;

// option 2: Factory function
template<class U>
auto wrap(U&& u) { return FooWrapper<std::remove_reference_t<U>>(std::forward<U>(u));}


// Usage example:

struct Foo {
  Foo(int a): a{a} {}
  Foo(const Foo& other) : a{other.a} {std::cout << "COPY!" << std::endl;}
  Foo(Foo&& other) : a{other.a} {std::cout << "MOVE!" << std::endl;}
  int a;
  auto foo() {return a;}
  auto special_foo() {return a + 42;}
};

auto fn1 (int sth) {
  Foo f{sth};
  FooWrapper w{f}; // w{Foo{sth}} would also have worked, and saved a copy
  return w;
}

FooWrapper<Foo> fn2 (int sth) {
  Foo f{sth};
  auto w = wrap(f); // w{Foo{sth}} would also have worked, and saved a copy
  return w;
}


int main(int argc, char*[]) {
  assert(fn1(argc).foo() == 43);
  assert(fn2(argc).foo() == 43);
}
```

Comment: Kind of depends on how portable you want your code to be.  If you want it to compile before C++17 then you are going to need to go the factory function route.  If you are okay limiting it C++17 or higher, then I personally prefer the CTAD route.

Answer (score 1):

> are the two approaches functionally equivalent in terms of type safety (and efficiency)?

In most cases yes, but there are behaviour difference when copy constructor is involved for example:

```
std::optional<int> o1;

auto o2 = std::optional(o1);      // std::make_optional<int>
auto o3 = std::make_optional(o1); // std::optional<std::optional<int>>.
```

It might be important (in generic code in particular).

> is one more idiomatic than the other since C++17?

I would go for CTAD by default.